# Receiving two different arrays over socket in a AsyncTask

Tags: java, sockets, android-asynctask

I have a Java server for a small multiplayer game. Over the connected socket I want to send to my client two different arrays when the keyword **update** arrives.

```
output.reset();
output.writeObject(array1);
output.writeObject(array2);
```

where array1 is **int[16]** and array2 is **int[2][2]**.

In the Android client I have **two** AsyncTask for catching the arrays.

```
@Override
protected int[] doInBackground(ObjectInputStream...params) {
    ObjectInputStream ois = params[0];

            try {
                arrayFromServer = (int[]) (ois.readObject());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

        return arrayFromServer;
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected int[][] doInBackground(ObjectInputStream... params) {
    ObjectInputStream ois = params[0];

        try {
            complexArrayFromServer = (int[][]) (ois.readObject());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return complexArrayFromServer;
}
```

and I am passing them to my UI activity like this with a timer who sends the keyword **update** every 20 seconds.

```
    public void startTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    initializeTimerTask();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 20000); 
}

public void initializeTimerTask() {

    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    //AsyncTask
                    new CardTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPostExecute(int[] result) {
                            mFromServer = result;
                        }
                    }.execute(ois);

                    //AsyncTask
                    new PointsAndCardsTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPostExecute(int[][] result) {
                            mComplexArray = result;

                        }
                    }.execute(ois);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

but that creates some problems to my game and I would love to know if I am doing something wrong in sending the **arrays** or is there a better way?

The error I am getting is

```
08-17 15:39:57.196: E/AndroidRuntime(665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 15:39:57.196: E/AndroidRuntime(665): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

because when expecting one array I am getting another.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to start a new thread with runnable to initalize AsyncTasks.

Comment: @andrewdleach I added that part because I used a Handler for the Timer...I don't need to do that?

Comment: Yeah. The only thing that an AsyncTask needs is a call to execute. Also, you need to move those on PostExecute calls into your subclassed AsyncTasks CardTask and PointsAndCardsTask

Comment: Also, consider using an AlarmManager with android code. It is written specifically for the Android Framework and can be started and stopped without managing threads.

Comment: @andrewdleach Ok thanks. I will check AlarmManager then. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: You got it @George Coder

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain what's going on within Java when it (de-)serializes such arrays but I'm really sure that Java isn't able to differ between the arrays so that you can't be sure to only get the array with the dimension(s) you want.

I would encapsulate the data you send within different Java objects. With doing that you can use `instance of` to ensure you only get what you want!